# ¿Por qué "cut" dice que "the delimiter must be a single character"?

Tags: bash

Symfony necesita escribir en el repertorio `var`.

He vaciado este directorio :

```
:/var/www/Symfony$ rm -rf var/*
```

Pero reconezco que no domino el siguiente comando :

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\ -f1`
```

Pero me dice el terminal :

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

He listado los procesos con `ps -aux` y aqui esta los processos que empiezan con www-data. Me dicen que utiliso `apache2` :

```
www-data  1254  0.0  0.1 282720  8160 ?        S    févr.22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1255  0.0  0.1 282720  8160 ?        S    févr.22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1256  0.0  0.1 282720  8160 ?        S    févr.22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1257  0.0  0.1 282720  8160 ?        S    févr.22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1258  0.0  0.1 282720  8160 ?        S    févr.22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tutorial que estás siguiendo quiere obtener el usuario con que corre tu webserver, ya sea `www-data`, `apache`, `nginx` etc, para meterlo en la variable de entorno HTTPDUSER.

Para eso, lista los procesos en curso (ps aux) y busca entre ellos los nombres más comunes del usuario webserver. Quita los procesos ejecutados por root (la misma búsqueda genera este proceso), y de los restantes, elige el primer valor.

El primer valor tiene la forma:

```
www-data  1503  0.0  0.0 129796  1564 ?        S    Feb20   0:01 nginx: worker process
```

De toda esa línea, lo que te interesa es sólo la primera "palabra", www-data. Con el comando cut explotas la fila en N elementos dado un separador, y ese separador en este caso debe ser un espacio. Por tanto, tu sentencia tiene que ser:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f1`
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Entonces despues de utilizar `ps aux` debo quitar los procesos ejecutados por root. ¿Como puedo quitarlos todos en el mismo tiempo ? ¿Quien serian los restantes ? ¿Los que no estan ejecutado por `root` son los ejecutados por `www-data` ?

Comment: No tienes que hacer nada. Sólo pegar el comando que te puse. El resto de lo que escribí era sólo una explicación de lo que hace cada parte de ese comando

Comment: Sin embargo todavía tengo una 404 con `localhost/Symfony`...

Comment: Y estás seguro que el problema es por permisos en `/var/www/Symfony/var` ? ¿Qué te muestra si tratar de ver simplemente `localhost`?

Comment: ̀Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page`. Pero ya no lo sé, cuando hice`:/var/www$ php symfony.phar new Symfony` , tuve `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0` y `preparing project ... Symfony 3.2.4 was successfully installed. Now you can:

    * Run your application:
        1. Execute the php bin/console server:start command.
        2. Browse to the http://localhost:8000 URL.`

Comment: ok, entonces entra a la carpeta de Symfony y desde ella ejecuta `php bin/console server:start`. Te está diciendo que en vez de levantar el proyecto con Apache lo va a levantar con el built-in server de php, en el puerto 8000

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Entonces `http://localhost:8000/Symfony` funciona ! ¿ Como hacer para obtener lo mismo en `localhost/Symfony` ?

Comment: Me dices que Symfony queda en `https://localhost:8000/Symfony` y no simplemente en `https://localhost:8000` ?

Comment: En el [tutorial de openclassrooms](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony/symfony-un-framework-php) supone el senor que alcanzamos lo mismo con `localhost/Symfony` pero necesito utilisar `https://localhost:8000/Symfony` . Ademas Pienso que tengo errores como lo muestre [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51060/por-qu%c3%a9-cut-dice-que-the-delimiter-must-be-a-single-character/51067?noredirect=1#comment90555_51067)

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de amenadiel es absolutamente correcta.

La utilidad `cut` necesita de un delimitador. Cuando dices `-d\ -f1` estás diciéndole que use el espacio pero de una forma incorrecta. ¿Por qué? Pues porque te falta un espacio:

```
cut -d\ -f1
#     ^^
#     esto indica que el delimitador es un espacio
```

Pero por tanto se traduce en:
    cut -d" "-f1

Donde falta un espacio antes de `-f1`. Por tanto, debes añadir otro y decir:

```
#       espacio antes de -f1
#       v
cut -d\  -f1
#     ^^
#     esto indica que el delimitador es un espacio
```

En lugar de eso, usa cualquiera de estas opciones:

```
$ echo "hola que tal" | cut -d\  -f2
que
$ echo "hola que tal" | cut -d" " -f2
que
```

---

Como complemento, déjame sugerir otra forma de extraer este resultado sin la necesidad de usar tantos comandos:

En lugar de decir:

```
grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f1`
```

¡Usa `awk` y hazlo de una sola vez!

```
awk '/[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx/ && !/root/ {print $1; exit}'
```

Fíjate que `awk '/AA/ && !/BB/'` selecciona aquellas líneas que contienen `AA` pero no `BB`. Después, `{print $1}` imprime la primera columna y `exit` sale del script, para solo obtener el primer resultado.